# View controller in portrait and subview in landscape

Tags: orientation, mpmovieplayercontroller, subview

I want my view controller to stay in portrait and I want my subview to be able to rotate acording to the device's orientation. How can I do that? I have a MPMoviePlayerController in a subview and I want to be able to watch the video in landscape but I want my main view controller to always stay in portrait. I have seen this done on many apps I just can't find the answer anywhere.

Here's my code.

```
-(IBAction)playMovie:(id)sender{

NSURL *fileURL   =   [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.thebasementonline.com/btv/NicoSmall.mov"];
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];  

[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate: self];
NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: &setCategoryError];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:moviePlayerController];

[self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;


[moviePlayerController play];
```

}

Comment: How about showing the player hosted by an additional view controller modally. That way you are free to show the player in any orientation you want to.

Comment: @Till I added some code. What's the best way to do that in my code?

Answer (score 0):

You could make this in your shouldRotateOrientation...

```
if(self.view.subviews containsObject:moviePlayer.view){
 return YES;
}
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
```

the problem is that if you remove the player view and it was in lanscape your main controller will be in landscape too :/  sooo u should use another view controller...